# sonar integration test coverage

Tags: testing, code-coverage, sonarqube

We have seperate integration test project which fires  the integration test cases on different modules . At present we do not have unit test cases within each module. We would like to ensure that the integration test covers most of the domain functionality.

Since we have the integration tests in a different project , Sonar always reports the test coverage as zero for the modules under test.
Is there any way to have the test coverage reported on a project , when the actual test is run from a different project

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want by reading the [Code Coverage documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project) on the wiki. Most notably, you'll be able to use the following sample project to see how it works:

- [IT JaCoCo Sonar Runner sample project](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/it/sonar-runner/it-jacoco-sonar-runner)

Basically, you have to run your integration tests first using JaCoCo to generate the coverage report (jacoco.exec) and then you reuse this report during the SonarQube analysis.